# adduser with a read / write to only one directory

Tags: linux, user-management, file-permissions, useradd

I have CentOS with one ssh user which is root.

How do I make one more user for my web developer so he can scp files over to /var/www/html ?
Its gonna be a static page, so mysql and alike are out of question. All I need is that user to be able to scp in and out files of /var/www/html

I tried to add user with home dir as /var/www/html by typing

```
# adduser -d /var/www/html webdev
```

but 

1. this user was not able to write files into this dir

2. he is able to browse other directories on the server

Comment: Which solution did you end up using?

Answer (score 1):

Why not setup a jail?  This will restrict a user to a specific directory when they log in.  There are a [variety](http://allanfeid.com/content/creating-chroot-jail-ssh-access) of [guides](http://www.fuschlberger.net/programs/ssh-scp-sftp-chroot-jail/) on how to do this, so take your pick.

Additionally, you can either add the user to a group that owns the files, or you can chown the files so that anybody can write to them.

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is that of permissions. There are many ways to solve the issue. However, since this is for development purposes, the easiest thing to do would be to:

1. Allow the user to upload files to his/her own home directory (typically ~/public_html).
2. Allow the web-server access to these files through user directory access.

If you want something with more isolation, I might even recommend something like OpenVZ (over-glorified chroot) to be used to provide the developer with their individual development environments instead.

PS: Remember to restrict the user access by using rssh as the user shell. This limits it to scp/sftp access only.